# Implementing validation for models in Railway

Tags: validation, node.js, railway.js

So I'm trying to get acquainted with [Railway.js](http://railwayjs.com/), thus I'm making a small application, part of which involves email validation on the model. Now:

-Taken from db/schema.js-

```
var User = describe('User', function () {
    property('email', String, { index : true });
    property('password', String);
    property('public_key', String);
});
```

-Taken from app/models/user.js-

```
User.validatesPresenceOf('email', 'password', 'public_key');
User.validatesFormatOf('email', ''); /* ARR HERE BE THE DRAGONS! */
```

So, I want to implement my own validation routine for emails, as I would like to check for existence of MX records, among other things, which regex can't solve. In any case, point is I can't see how to approach this, and the official docs aren't much help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after actually thinking over it again, I realized that Railway.js uses [JugglingDB](https://github.com/1602/jugglingdb), which lead me to check the repository. Well, the key was in [JugglingDB's docs](http://1602.github.com/jugglingdb/validatable.html#class/validate).

Comment: Posting an example of how you solved it would definitely help those passing by this question...